# Limit Quartz jobs to particular worker

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I have a scheduler engine for a web application running in quartz.net, which is working well.  This scheduler handles many routine but important tasks, such as sending daily email etc.

However I now have a new requirement for the application, bringing in some high frequency jobs (1 job per second).

I'd ideally run this using the same job queue, and with all the error handling and notifications already built.  I also want to reuse some of the actual job types in the high frequency bit.

However, due to the different nature of the jobs, I'd much prefer to run a dedicated worker server(s) for the 1 second stuff, so the resource is partitioned.

Is there a way in quartz.net, using the same queue and job types, to restrict certain jobs to run on certain workers in this way?  Ideally this would be based on the trigger meta data or similar.  I have read through the documentation and googled for a few hours but haven't found anything describing this kind of control.

Answer (score 0):

With Java Quartz there's the Quartz Where functionality that might address this. It allows choosing host to run jobs with based on parameters like load, name etc. This however, is not ported to .NET world (it's closed source and would require engineering from scratch).

You could implement your requirements by using two different schedulers. It's perfectly legal to host multiple schedulers and share the database, just have a different scheduler instance based on your partitioning needs. You can also tweak the thread priority if you'd go the route of running the instances on the same box.